# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am getting this error while building. I referred to other answers here, but none of them worked for me.

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/externalPoc
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=
spring.database.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface CardRepository extends JpaRepository<CardRegistration, Serializable> {
    Optional<Card> findByUuid(String uuid);
}
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Card extends AbstractBaseEntity implements Serializable {

    String uuid;
    String validFrom;
    String validTo;


    public String getValidFrom() {
        return validFrom;
    }

    public void setValidFrom(String validFrom) {
        this.validFrom = validFrom;
    }

    public String getValidTo() {
        return validTo;
    }

    public void setValidTo(String validTo) {
        this.validTo = validTo;
    }

    public String getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    public void setUuid(String uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

}
```

and pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.start.new.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>externalAdapterPoc</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>externalPoc</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.13.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <springfox-swagger.version>2.7.0</springfox-swagger.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
          <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
          <version>9.4-1206-jdbc42</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- swagger -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ma.glasnost.orika</groupId>
            <artifactId>orika-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path-assert</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20171018</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

And main class (spring boot application)

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.start.new.project.externalPoc.model.repository")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.start.new.project.externalPoc.model")
public class ExternalPocApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ExternalPocApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public MapperFacade mapper() {
        MapperFactory mapperFactory = new DefaultMapperFactory.Builder().build();
        return mapperFactory.getMapperFacade();
    }
}
```

I removed all the folder from .m2 directory. Ran mvn clean install again. Got the same error. 
The service class Autowires the repository. 
And controllers use @RestController annotation.

And this is the exact cause:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#4d3ca6c7': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor
>   argument; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available

Comment: I found class `EntityManagerFactory` should be in [javax.persistance package](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/package-summary.html), so maybe just you need [this dependecy](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.persistence/javax.persistence) to pom file? Just guessing

Comment: didn't work :( ..

Comment: Is that all your code ? It seems like you try to create bean where you use entityManagerFactory but you forgot to create it before

Comment: Yeah, that's all the code. I didn't add controller and services.

Answer (score 1):

Create a dummy project from https://start.spring.io (Choose `Switch to the full version and tick PostGres, for example`) and add your classes to that project afterwards.

That way you don't have to bother about the dependencies and you would get the latest by default. I had used it yesterday and it worked like a charm for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add `@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = ("Name of your entityManagerFactory bean class").class)` on top of the service class where you are autowiring the bean. Also add `@Component` or its derived annotation on top of the `entityManagerFactory` bean class

Comment: What is entityManagerFactory bean class ? Is it the Entity? or Repository?

Comment: The bean class means that entityManagerFactory looks like a variable (for e.g. String string; here string is an variable of Class String). Now whatever Class the variable belongs to you put its name or one of its implementations(if its an interface) in place of the parentheses
If you could provide a link to your actual code where the the variable is declared, I might be able to help better :)