Facing issue with SpringBoot3 Upgrade entityManager
I am currently in process of migrating an application from Spring boot 2.7.0 to 3.3.3(java17). I have updated the soring starter and all associated dependencies. However, on starting of the application I am facing an issue
Logs:
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManager
"message":"Error creating bean with name 'UserDetailsService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository': Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.mazdl.studio.repository.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on StudioApplication: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManager'","name":"org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException"
StudioApplication.java
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.mazdl.studio")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.mazdl.studio"})
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EntityScan("com.mazdl.studio.entity")
@EnableCaching
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class StudioApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
   
    SpringApplication.run(StudioApplication.class, args);
}

Can anyone help on this?
I have tried to give the basepackages in Jparepositories .
Can anyone help on this?
I have  added all the necessary annotations and also tried to give the basepackages in Jparepositories .

Why on earth do you have all those annotations on there? Ditch all of them and just leave @SpringBootApplication all the others aren't needed. Please add the full error/stacktrace you get (using code formatting!) and add your dependencies and application.properties.

Hello, please post the source code for userRepository, including the package declaration. Also consider posting the code for service - and any other files you consider relevant.

Also take into account the accepted answer to the following question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53140135/cannot-resolve-reference-to-bean-entitymanagerfactory-while-setting-constructo You appear to be using a custom emf name jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory
